# Сount how many requests there were to a specific document

Tags: elasticsearch, caching, search, full-text-search

I'm using elasticsearch index as a cache table for some kind of search API.
I am currently using the following mapping:

```
{
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": False,
            "properties": {
                "query_str": {"type": "text"},
                "search_results": {
                    "type": "object", 
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "query_embedding": {
                    "type": "dense_vector",
                    "dims": 768,
                },
               
        }
    }
```

The cache search is performed via embedding vector similarity. So if the embedding of the new query is close enough to a cached one, it is considered as a cache hit, and search_results field is returned to the user.

I want to clear cached search results due to their unpopularity among users (i.e. low cache hitrate). Because of that, I need to count how many cache hits (i.e. request hits) there were to each document for a certain period of time (last month for example).

I understand, that I can explicitly add a `hit_rate` field and update it every time when the new query hits some cashed query, but **is there a more elegant way to do this** (maybe via some built-in elasticsearch statistic)?

Comment: did you check ILM policy ? you can add date field with the each document and then configured ILM policy and delete document which is not updated in last few days or months.

Comment: That's not what I need. I want to sort documents by the number of requests to them, not the date

Comment: ok.. then you cant do without extra field which will increase every time when request is hit. there is no other way or default functionality in elastic which will do this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Actually the App Search product has an analytics feature that records the document clicks and uses a different index to do that (also store the search query).